# Retrieve the value of multiple select boxes javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select

Hello I am having a small problem, I have about 4 select boxes each with different values in them for the user to choose from these are created dynamically in a loop within **java script** so they all share the same id.

I want to print each value selected dynamically so when you select from select box 1 print its value then when selecting box 2's option the first value is overridden.

The code I have now only works for the first select box, can anyone help me get it working for them all?

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    var a=document.createElement("select"); 
    aa.setAttribute('id', 'boxes');
    //..addoptions in another loop then in the same loop I have
    aa.onchange = function(){ tester();};
}


function tester(){
    var i = document.getElementById("boxes");
    var ii = i.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementsById("pTag").innerHTML=i.options[ii].value
}
```

Javascript only please

Comment: As you have stated, they have the same id therefore `document.getElementsById("pTag")` will always return the first select and hence the reason only the first select is updating. Use different ID's for the selects. If you can also include how you are creating the select boxes it will be much easier to help out.

Comment: This makes sense, I am creating my select boxes in a loop so for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ var a=document.createElement("select"); aa.setAttribute('id', 'boxes'); .. and then i add the options

Comment: It's hard to help out, edit your question and add the other code that makes a reference to the code you have put in. If it is a `onclick` or `onchange` event executing that it will be much easier to point out how to fix your issue. But for now use different ID's, `a=document.createElement("select"); a.id = "boxes"+i";` should do the job.

Comment: i have edited it, I tried to change my id the way you said to but im not sure how I could improve the tgester() function to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as follows it should fix your problem. Notice that `aa.onchage = tester` and not `aa.onchange = tester()` the reason is because you are assigning `aa.onchange` to the function `tester` and not its return value.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    var a=document.createElement("select"); 
    aa.setAttribute('id', 'boxes'+i);
    //..addoptions in another loop then in the same loop I have
    aa.onchange = tester;
}


function tester(event){
    document.getElementsById("pTag").innerHTML = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: great this works thank you so much wasted too much time on this

Comment: Its always a good idea to mark it as a solution to your problem.